# MVC - CSS links

Tags: php, html, css, model-view-controller

I am relatively new to this whole MVC structure for web apps.

Here is the structure of my project.

[image]

The file you see on the right of the picture is inside the 'Views' folder.

When I want to link a css file, why does the path have to be `href="/css/stylePortfolio.css"`

Why is it not `href="../../public/css/stylePortfolio.css"`?

Comment: How did you bootstrap this?

Comment: @Chay22 what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Because your site root path is index.php folder, your public folder when you have CSS folder.

Comment: because the `href` attribute is a url, not a file path.

Comment: @miceli Can you explain in more detail? What is a site root path? How do you set it? And how does this affect the whole structure?

Comment: The root path is index.php folder. It is "entry point" for your website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking at, is the HTML that is sent to the users' browser. The browser does not know anything about the structure of your application. It simply reads that `href` link, and downloads the file from `http://example.com<link>`, where `<link>` is `/css/main.css` for example.

When configured correctly, the **web root** of your website is in your **/public** folder. That means, anything that a browser requests, is **relative to your web root**. Thus, if you want to link to a css file, you need to think of that link relatively to your projects **web root**, **not relatively to your project root**.

An example:
Say, you create a new project in `/home/user/AwesomePhpProject`.
Now, `/home/user/AwesomePhpProject` is called your **project root**.

In your project root, you create a directory, `public`. You configure that directory to be your **web root**, using `VirtualHost` (when using Apache) or the `root` directive (when using Nginx).
`/home/user/AwesomePhpProject/public` is now your **web root**.
When a browser requests `/css/main.css`, it will be directed to `/css/main.css` **relative** to your **web root**. In our case, that will be `/home/user/AwesomePhpProject/public/css/main.css`.

Most modern applications separate the project and web root, for security reasons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm starting to understand.
Could you elaborate a bit?

ex: What is a web root? What is a project root? How are they separated?

Answer (score 2):

As your `index.php` is inside the public folder, so all the views are loading in the public folder. That is why you should declare the CSS path from the public root. You can modify the path if necessary.

In this case, you can declare a **global variable** or **constant** your main controller with the path of your CSS folder

```
define('CSS_PATH', 'http://localhost/fab/public/css/');
```

Now use this like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=CSS_PATH?>bootstrap.css">
```

Comment: when I do this I get the error
`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://fab.app/fab.app/public/css/bootstrap.min.css".`

Comment: Add this to your `.htaccess` and let me know `AddType text/css .css `

Comment: I did it. No difference. The problem is that the path is wrong.
It's `http://fab.app/fab.app/public/css/bootstrap.min.css`
when it should be `"http://fab.app/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: Is it solved? If not then could you show me the line you defined in PHP?

Comment: You are right. I had not included the `http://` part of the line in php.

Now the error is what you tried to solve before: `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://fab.app/public/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

So the path is correct but it doesn't interpret it as css.

Comment: In this case please debug and check the value of the constant. Echo it like `echo "CSS_PATH"`. That must be work if there is no error in this code.

Comment: As I think,  you are working on your PC not online. If you are working locally, you must add `localhost` in front of the link as I said before in my answer like `define('CSS_PATH', 'http://localhost/fab.app/public/css/');`

Comment: I am using homestead so this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

It's because front-end links (like CSS and JS) are relative from current file you are in. And since your root is in `public` you have to specify **URL** from this directory (you can't link to any file in top level of root).

Answer (score 0):

`Why is it not href="../../public/css/stylePortfolio.css"?`

Because entry point of your MVC is index.php from public folder. So all your css and js links should be relative to public folder